# Modify Sidenavigation Which Highlights Which Part of Page is Viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a sidenavigation bar which continually checks the users scroll position and if it is greater than a specified .slide height, it adds a class .current to a certain div on a sidebar making it turn orange and thus indicates which part of a page the user is on. Right now, the code only works for one specific height of .slide but I would like to modify it so that each slide (i.e. slide red, slide green, slide blue which are the divs with the colored background) can be of different heights since my content for each section will vary in length.

The fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/P4NKg/5/)

JavaScript:

```
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > $('.slide').height()*$('.current').index()){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        var newSlide = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / $('.slide').height());
        $('.sidenavigation li:eq('+newSlide+')').addClass('current');
    }
    if($(window).scrollTop() < $('.slide').height()*$('.current').index()){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        var newSlide = Math.floor($(window).scrollTop() / $('.slide').height());
        $('.sidenavigation li:eq('-newSlide-')').addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to help you with your code and then i realize how hard it is, so I know it is probably not what you really want, but I recommend you a great jQuery plugin, which will solve your problem very fast: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: that seems like it could work, but is there no simple solution to my problem. I was thinking just to have a four separate codes for each slide and to test for adding .current to one sidebar div only (each code would have the height of each background div's id), but I'm not proficcient enough in JavaScript to write it.

Comment: It wouldn't be much efficient. Performance of the code would be really bad, because you would check four separated codes every single pixel scroll.

Comment: could you just do multiple if statements each one checking a separate slide, but still all in one scroll code?